# Mongo-python issue

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am running a python application on Mongodb using pymongo, the application is performing basic read and write operations on it, the problem is that the application stops in between for unknown reasons and when i restart, it runs normally as if nothing happend until the same issue repeats.[Error on application crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9CUG.png)

Please check the link for image of the error.

Comment: You need to test that request if it respond successfully.

Comment: It is good practice to post the error traceback into your question along with the code that is generating the error (you can remove any sensitive parts)

Comment: is mongodb installed on the host system?? bcz it looks like a connection  timeout to me

Comment: @SteveRossiter please click on "Error on application crash" it will give you the error

Comment: @armak the db is on a server and my application is remotely accessing it and yes it does seem like a timeout error but why is it happening could it be a network issue?,  i am not very sure i cannot have this happening on production so could you please help out.

Comment: @AkshayAwasthy use a try catch whenever you use pymong queries and catch the `TimeoutError` and retry for some `threshold` value. and if it does not connect. just handle that gracefully.